# Swift Inheritance nested/inner enum issue

Tags: swift, inheritance, inner-classes

I am coming from java/C++/C# to Swift. I have the following issue:

```
class A {

    struct Fields{
      static let valA = "A";
    }
}

class B: A {

    struct Fields{
      static let valB = "B";
      static let valD = "D";
    }
}

var b: B = B()
println("\(B.Fields.valB)")
```

The compiler is complaining that "Class A.Fields.Type has no member named "valB".

I need to keep the same enum name (eq. Fields) on both classes.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you need to inherit the contents of `Fields` from class `A` in class `B`? Or are the two `Fields` structures completely unrelated? Also, your code doesn't produce any error for me in Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 1):

instead of struct, make it class

```
class A {

    class Fields{
        static let valA = "A";
    }
}

class B: A { //<--Doesn't have to extend A 

    class Fields : A.Fields{
        static let valB = "B";
        static let valD = "D";
    }
}


println(B.Fields.valA)//A
println(B.Fields.valB)//B
println(B.Fields.valD)//D
```

**edit:** 
why class and not struct?
struct can't be inherited

```
struct A{
    var a : Int?;
}

struct B :A{
    var b : Int;
}
```

this will generate compile error

> Inheritance from non-protocol type 'A'

only classes can be inherited and only classes can extend other classes.
this code will also generate compile error:

```
class A{
    var e : Int?;
}

struct B :A{
    var t : Int;
}
```

> Non-class type 'B' cannot inherit from class 'A'

dont forget that structs comes from C language, which is not object oriented.

Comment: Could you also answer why it not works with structs?